# Crear carpeta con la variable del día

Tags: python-3.x

Soy nuevo con Python. Quiero verificar si existe una carpeta y si no es así crearla (usando `date-time`), pero cuando llamo a esta variable me da error. Adjunto el codigo, y desde ya muchas gracias.

```
######## Fecha para creacion de carpetas ##########
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
dia = date.strftime('%d')
  
####### Comprobacion de carpeta ########

import os
def crear_carpeta():
    nombre_carpeta = "C:\\"
   if os.path.isdir = ('nombre_carpeta\dia'):
    else:
    print(f'no existe, se crea')
    os.mkdir('nombre_carpeta\dia'')
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Agrega el error que te sale.. y creo que nombre_carpeta lo querias usar como una variable, y ahi lo estas pasando como una cadena...

Answer (score 1):

```
######## Fecha para creacion de carpetas ##########
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
dia = date.strftime('%d')

####### Comprobacion de carpeta ########
import os
def crear_carpeta():
    nombre_carpeta = "C:\\\\Users\\Angel\\Desktop"
    if not os.path.isdir(str(nombre_carpeta) + '\\' + str(dia)):
        print('No existe, se crea')
        os.mkdir(str(nombre_carpeta) + '\\' + str(dia))
crear_carpeta()
```

He corregido algunos errores de sintaxis, indentación, etc.

El código comprueba si existe una carpeta con el número de día (por ejemplo, 28). Si no existe, la crea en el directorio que se indica.

Para usar el valor `\` hay que escribir `\\` porque sino Python lo interpreta como un caracter de escape. [Más información (en inglés)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp).

Por supuesto, tienes que sustituir Angel por tu nombre de usuario del equipo para que te funcione correctamente.

Comment: Gracias ante todo por la pronta respuesta, y la explicación del inconveniente. Disculpa las molestias ocasionadas. Saludos.-

Comment: Ninguna molestia. Me alegro de que se haya solucionado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Particularmente esto:

```
if os.path.isdir = ('nombre_carpeta\dia'):
    else:
    print(f'no existe, se crea')
    os.mkdir('nombre_carpeta\dia'')}
```

Tiene varios problemas:

1. `os.path.isdir` es una función, ¿que hace el `=` en el medio, en todo caso sería algo así: `if os.path.isdir('nombre_carpeta\dia'):`
2. Ahora el problema es esta cadena `'nombre_carpeta\dia'`, ¿estás asumiendo que las variables se concatenan automágicamente? pues no, el path termina siendo el literal `'nombre_carpeta\dia'`
3. Si necesitas usar las variables para generar el path, te recomiendo, por un lado evitar las variables globales, y por el otro hacer uso de `os.path.join()` para construir el path completo, esto evita problemas con el separador de carpetas en función del SO.
4. Hay problemas de identación, pero tal vez sea un problema del copiar/pegar.

Con estas consideración, podría sugerirte algo como esto:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

def crear_carpeta():
  date = datetime.now()
  dia = date.strftime('%d')
  
  nombre_carpeta = os.path.join("C:", dia)
  if not os.path.isdir(nombre_carpeta):
    print(f'no existe, se crea')
    os.mkdir(nombre_carpeta)
```

Comment: Patricio como le dije a Angel, muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta, me con sus explicaciones me aclararon mejor el panorama. Abrazo!